# Do I have to to use CollectionResponse as a return type in GAE Endpoints APIs or I can use java collections of entities?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

It *appears* that I can safely use plain java collections as return types (as long as they contain entities) in my Endpoint APIs. I was wondering if I'm missing something. Is there any benefit to using CollectionResponse instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use collections ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types)). The advantage of CollectionResponse is the built in support for paging and other nice-to-have features.

Comment: How about for private methods in your API that are not exposed to the API -  should one work entirely in CollectionResponse's?